# If $[x]$ denotes the integral part of x, find $\int^{\infty}_0 [2e^{-x}]dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

If $[x]$ denotes the integral part of x, find $\int^{\infty}_0 [2e^{-x}]dx$

My approach : 
Since I know the following integral :

$\int^{1.5}_0 [x^2]dx = \int^1_0 [x^2]dx +  \int^{\sqrt{2}}_0 [x^2]dx +\int^{(1.5)}_{\sqrt{2}} [x^2]dx$

$\Rightarrow \int^{1.5}_0 [x^2]dx =\int^1_0 0 dx +  \int^{\sqrt{2}}_0 1 dx +\int^{(1.5)}_{\sqrt{2}} 2 dx$

But how to break the given limit of given integral please suggest it will be of great help thanks

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Note that the integrand is $0$ after $\ln 2$. What is it before then?